# Apply changes in Jupyter Notebook config file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Is there any way to apply the changes made to the Jupyter Notebook config file without restarting the server? Restarting the kernel seems not do it.

Comment: I'm interested in this since I'm working with remotely hosted notebooks, where I'm unable to change the config file (e.g. IO data rate) and restart the server.